# How to set Width and Height of FrameLayout dynamically android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, classcastexception, android-framelayout

I am trying to set the width and height of 2 frame layouts which are the containers for 2 fragments, both being children of a Linear Layout.

However whenever I set width and height of the layout with

```
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
```

it is resulting in a class cast Exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Answer (score 15):

use this method ...

```
.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
```

instead of your method ....

```
.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100)
```

**Note:- `ClassCastException` problem happen when your class is different other class, you want to cast....**

Comment: you are welcome ... and remember the exception for next time

Answer (score 10):

This answer is actually complementary, as some people already explained the solution, but I wanted to clarify the question further more.

As mentioned above, you must set the parameters to the PARENT view and not to the view itself. You said that the FrameLayouts are inside **LinearLayouts**, so you must set the parameters for that.

That is the reason why you got the exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

The compiler is telling you exactly that, you cannot cast **FrameLayout parameters** to a LinearLayout.

From [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html):

> LayoutParams are used by views to tell **their parents** how they want to be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child view attributes that this class supports.

Hope that clarifies the question even more!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code."gameframe" is the name of the frameLayout.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gameFrame.getLayoutParams();
params.width = New_width;
params.height = New_height;      
gameFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception report gives you a hint. It looks like the parent layout of your FrameLayout is a LinearLayout. So, you need to set LinearLayout params for your FrameLayout. Try the following:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(your_width, your_height);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Yes I agree absolutely, I also noticed that you cannot set the layout params if your parent layout is a relative layout

Comment: @JayakrishnanMenon glad that helped.