# How to trigger the onsizechanged for framelayout

Tags: android, video

I am using the customised view by extending the Frame layout  to play videos 
In my screen half screen i am playing the video . In the bottom showing the list of videos. When i select the first video on size changed called and then the video view is setting the size when i change another video with different resolution is also fitted to initial video size.
I want update the video size based on selected video 
So how to trigger the on size changed() method on every video selection 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of an FrameLayout dynamically like shown below:

`frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100,100)`

For more information:
[How to set width and height of framelayout dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038105/how-to-set-width-and-height-of-framelayout-dynamically-android)